# Calculating a multiplication of large number of matrices takes a long time

Tags: matrix, timing

I have a multiplication of matrices, say

M1.G1.M2.G2.....Mn.Gn, here n may reach 100. M and G are 4 4 matrices and their elements are function of s. Mathematica takes so long to perform this multiplication. However, if I divided it such that
p1=M1.G1.M2.G2...M10.G10;
P2=M11.G11....M20.G20
.
.
p10=M91.G91....M100.G100;

and evaluate each line separately, it becomes faster?!

Comment: Which version, and which exact syntax? When I evaluate `Dot @@ RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {200, 4, 4}]` the multiplication is rapid?

Comment: version 10, but my matrices's element are function of unkown parameter s

Comment: See also: [(83412)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/83412/121)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a bit of `Partition` you can use `ParallelMap` to spread the `Dot` over your available kernels.

You have symbolic entries in your matrix but I'll use numeric entries since I don't have access to your equations. A performance gain is realised and I'm hoping it is transferable to your symbolic problem.

`mList` is taken to be the list of your $M_n$ matrices and `gList` the list of your $G_n$ matrices.

```
mList = Table[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {4, 4}], 1000];
gList = Table[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {4, 4}], 1000];
```

In `rif` the list are `Riffle`d to get them in order of the `Dot` operation.

```
rif = Riffle[mList, gList];
```

Now on to the interesting part. We want to partition this list so that we have as many sublists as we have Mathematica kernels on the machine.  First `LaunchKernels` is called to load all kernels that the licence allows.  This also updates `$KernelCount` to the number of kernels available; needed for the partitioning.

```
LaunchKernels[];
With[{n = Floor[Length[rif]/$KernelCount]},
 prif = Partition[rif, n, n, 1, {}];
 ]
```

I have 4 physical cores which with my parallel settings in Mathematica creates a total of 4 kernels.

Now `Dot` can be mapped in parallel to each of the sublists in `prif` with `ParallelMap`.  This gives a list of `$KernelCount` entries with each entry the result of the `Dot` of the `prif` sublist. `Dot` is `Apply`'ed (`@@`) to this list for the final result.

```
Dot @@ ParallelMap[Apply[Dot, #] &, prif, 1, Method -> "CoarsestGrained"]
```

This executes in half the time taking 0.0437 seconds while non-parallel `Dot@@rif` takes 0.894 seconds.

---

**Feedback to Wolfram**

One thing I'd like to see is an extension of the `Method -> "ItemsPerEvaluation"` option.  As it is now you can only specify an upper limit to the number of entries in each evaluation.  However, many functions require at least 2 parameters as `Dot` in this question. In order to insure that this happens for the function we are currently forced to do `Partition` tricks with `Apply`. Could `"ItemsPerEvaluation"` be extended to allow for a lower (`l`) and upper (`u`) bound as follows.

```
Method -> "ItemsPerEvaluation" -> {l, u}
```

With this we could simply the above (removing the partitioning) to either of the following:

```
ParallelCombine[Dot, rif, Dot, Method -> "ItemsPerEvaluation" -> {2, Automatic}]
```

or

```
Dot @@ ParallelMap[Dot, rif, 1, Method -> "ItemsPerEvaluation" -> {2, Automatic}]
```