# multiplication of 4*4 matrices whose elements are function of x and y

Tags: matrix

I have a matrix 4*4 M whose elements are a function of x and y. I would like to multiply this matrix for different values of x and y, say

M[1,1].M[2,2]......M[n,n]. How I can do it?

Comment: You wrote the answer yourself on the last line of your post.  What are you looking for beyond this?

Comment: So, something like `Dot @@ (M @@@ {{x1, y1}, ..., {xn, yn}})`?

Comment: Ok, but say that n is 1000. How i can do it in this case?

Comment: Ex. this one is not working Dot[Table[M[i, i], {i, 0, 4}]]

Comment: You didn't see my comment on `Dot @@`?

Comment: i saw it, and that exactly what i am looking for.

Comment: You could use `Array[m[#, #] &, 4, 1, Dot]`.  Since you mention different values of `x` and `y` perhaps also e.g. `Array[m, {2, 3}, 1, Dot]`.  By the way be sure to read [(83072)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/83072/121), [(83412)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/83412/121)

Comment: Thanx Mr.Wizard

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 2):

Hasan,

So you have a matrix defined something like this (with the right hand side something else, presumably)?

```
hMatrix[x_, y_] := {{x, 0, 0, 0}, {0, y, 0, 0}, {x, y, x + y, 0}, {0, 0, 0, x y}}
```

So then you can make a list for hMatrix[1,1], hMatrix[2,2], ... etc. like this (change 5 to any other number):

```
hMatrices = Table[hMatrix[i, i], {i, 5}]
```

And then you can apply a function, like Dot or Times, to these matrices:

```
Apply[ Dot, hMatrices ]
```

Comment: Welcome back!  Long time no see.

Comment: thank u very much Arnoud Buzing