# Why FoldList 5 times faster than Apply for matrix multiplication?

Tags: matrix, performance-tuning

Consider this list of $2\times 2$ matrices:

```
list=RandomReal[{-2,2},{500,2,2}];
```

Now compare timings of `Apply` and `FoldList` for matrix multiplication:

```
t1=FoldList[Dot,list];//AbsoluteTiming
(* 0.000324, Null *)
t2=Apply[Dot,list];//AbsoluteTiming
(* 0.001526, Null *)
```

Clearly, as it should be, `Last@t1==t2` returns `True`. I wonder why `FoldList` is 5 times faster than `Apply` although it does also compute the same matrix multiplication... Is it maybe because `FoldList` effectively only computes the `Dot` product of only two matrices to get the next element - whereas `Apply` maybe uses some partitioning?

There is some evidence for the latter, since

```
t3=Apply[Dot,Dot@@@Partition[list,20,20,1,{}]];//AbsoluteTiming
(* 0.000944, Null *)
```

achieves much better timing than the standard `Apply`, but is still a little bit slower than `FoldList` (it seems that `20` is kind of the optimal value for manually partitioning `list` in order to speed up `Apply[Dot,...]`).

```
$Version="10.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (December 4, 2014)"
(* actually, it is 10.0.2 *)
```

So, in brief:

1. Am I right that `FoldList` is faster because it only computes `Dot` product between two matrices?
2. Is there another way to achieve the output of `FoldList` but even faster?

Comment: Why not `t3 = Fold[Dot, list]`?

Comment: @kglr This is a nice alternative to the result for `Apply`. However, I also need the intermediate results of `Dot` between all previous matrices and the following one, as `FoldList` does.

Comment: I am using version `10.0.2` on 64bit Linux (edited that into the question)

Comment: Maybe some clue is in the relative sizes of the files produced when you execute `Trace[Dot @@ list] >> "tr1.txt";
Trace[Fold[Dot, list]] >> "tr2.txt";`  `FoldList` seems to know that it is only going to use the next $2\times2$ list at each step, but `Dot` carries the full list at each step

Comment: @JasonB Nice observation. This is also pointing towards the direction I was thinking about, but had no real idea how to "verify" (+1)

Comment: Related: [(83072)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/83072/121), [(83412)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/83412/121)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is as you suspect - when you evaluate `Dot[m1, m2, m3, m4, m5, ......m1000]` the process is something like this:

1. Look at the input: `Dot[m1, m2, m3, m4, m5, ......m1000]`
2. Evaluate the first matrix product, `m12=m1.m2`
3. Look at the input:  `Dot[m12, m3, m4, m5, ......m1000]`
4. Evaluate the first matrix product, `m123=m12.m3`
5. Look at the input:  `Dot[m123, m4, m5, ......m1000]`

and so on.  When you use `Fold`, the process is

1. Look at the input `Fold[ Dot, {m1, m2, m3, m4, m5, ......m1000]`
2. Evaluate `m12 = m1.m2`
3. Evaluate `m123 = m12.m3`
4. Evaluate `m1234 = m123.m4`

and so on.  So you don't have to carry the whole list of matrices with you at each step, you only ask for the next element of the list of matrices.  This is verified by evaluating:

```
Trace[Dot @@ list] >> "tracedot.txt";
```

The full result is 11MB, and uploaded [here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jasondbiggs/ab3f4b17c6198c4b7574918b24c12532/raw/9f7520bdd1d373be72554cb522a88e1dad07340b/tracedot.txt), but we can just look at the last few steps to see the process:

> ```
>  HoldForm[{{-5.321520990180708*^61, 6.819103101378474*^62}, 
>    {-2.114430818780517*^61, 2.7094738103263247*^62}} . {{-1.7819423969909707, 
>    -1.6334482227548142}, {0.6782967903343957, -1.147772651519678}} . 
>    {{1.9417458764159523, -0.6657483830965161}, {0.1976190389456658, 
>    -1.5228205915198982}} . {{1.498197940123715, -0.6704111046106744}, 
>    {1.9988680712366937, -1.2709354099712966}} . {{0.9483227326875721, 
>    -0.9780900034931443}, {1.2872284244010022, 1.4851315661557898}} . 
>    {{0.1761339992709079, -0.4328681525925324}, {-1.8705391562731704, 
>    0.17175870343138833}}], HoldForm[{{5.5736401335123805*^62, 
>    -6.957537147278919*^62}, {2.214606781188385*^62, 
>    -2.7644786131938665*^62}} . {{1.9417458764159523, -0.6657483830965161}, 
>    {0.1976190389456658, -1.5228205915198982}} . {{1.498197940123715, 
>    -0.6704111046106744}, {1.9988680712366937, -1.2709354099712966}} . 
>    {{0.9483227326875721, -0.9780900034931443}, {1.2872284244010022, 
>    1.4851315661557898}} . {{0.1761339992709079, -0.4328681525925324}, 
>    {-1.8705391562731704, 0.17175870343138833}}], 
>  HoldForm[{{9.447650941400094*^62, 6.884438927293232*^62}, 
>    {3.753889978530132*^62, 2.735434073217245*^62}} . {{1.498197940123715, 
>    -0.6704111046106744}, {1.9988680712366937, -1.2709354099712966}} . 
>    {{0.9483227326875721, -0.9780900034931443}, {1.2872284244010022, 
>    1.4851315661557898}} . {{0.1761339992709079, -0.4328681525925324}, 
>    {-1.8705391562731704, 0.17175870343138833}}], 
>  HoldForm[{{2.7915536339558937*^63, -1.5083487314081891*^63}, 
>    {1.1091842063211788*^63, -5.9932095523871395*^62}} . {{0.9483227326875721, 
>    -0.9780900034931443}, {1.2872284244010022, 1.4851315661557898}} . 
>    {{0.1761339992709079, -0.4328681525925324}, {-1.8705391562731704, 
>    0.17175870343138833}}], HoldForm[{{7.057044096191614*^62, 
>    -4.970487017372562*^63}, {2.804016286699628*^62, 
>    -1.9749524531188776*^63}} . {{0.1761339992709079, -0.4328681525925324}, 
>    {-1.8705391562731704, 0.17175870343138833}}], 
>  HoldForm[{{9.421789131712158*^63, -1.15920136959471*^63}, 
>   {3.74361415559633*^63, -4.6059220767264225*^62}}]}
> ```

The entire list of remaining matrices is carried through to each evaluation step.  Compare this with

```
Trace[Fold[Dot, list]] >> "tracefolddot.txt";
```

which is only 93kb, uploaded [here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jasondbiggs/f385a8792cc6cfc3e83787f98df9c721/raw/77132224bbc8a142a64c8e768ddaa6b714afa0de/tracefolddot.txt) and essentially looks like

> ```
> {{HoldForm[list], HoldForm[(* List of matrices here *)]}, 
>  HoldForm[Fold[Dot, (*List of matrices here again *)]], 
>  HoldForm[{{9.421789131712158*^63, -1.15920136959471*^63}, 
>   {3.74361415559633*^63, -4.6059220767264225*^62}}]}
> ```

This carrying through of all the remaining matrices in the list is enough to account for the performance difference I think.