# How can I compute the dot product of an arbitrary number of matrices?

Tags: matrix

First I make an example with three matrices.

```
M[1] = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
M[2] = {{1.1, 2.1}, {3.1, 4.1}};
M[3] = {{1.2, 2.2}, {3.2, 4.2}};
```

I want to calculate

```
M[1].M[2].M[3]
```

so that is my code

```
For[m = 1, m <= 3, m = m + 1, M1[m] = Dot[M[m], M1[m - 1]]]
```

where

```
M1[0] = {{1, 0}, {0, 1}};
```

`M1[3]` should be the result I want, but When I run the code, the return value is

> ```
> {{1.2, 2.2}, {3.2, 4.2}}.Dz1[2]
> ```

So I want to know: what is wrong in my code and how can I correct it?

Comment: why not `M[1].M[2].M[3]` or `Dot[M[1] , M[2], M[3]]`?

Comment: as a matter of fact, the number of the matrix is n (very big), so I must write a code to calculate

Comment: The code    DZ1[2], should be M1[2]

Comment: Possibly relevant: [(83072)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/83072/121), [(83412)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/83412/121), [(112125)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/112125/121)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want a way to generate the dot product of $n$ terms, you can use [`Array`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Array.html) to generate the list and [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html) [`Dot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dot.html) to the result:

```
Dot @@ Array[M, 5]
(* M[1].M[2].M[3].M[4].M[5] *)
```

Answer (score 1):

**My apologies, when I started writing I had not seen the above answer. I do not delete mine because I also have some comments below, but if a moderator does not agree feel free to delete it.**

As a toy example, I set 5 identical matrices `{{1,1},{1,2}}` and call them `A1,..,E1`. So `list={A1,B1,C1,D1,E1}`

```
Dot @@ list
```

gives the desired result

> {{34, 55}, {55, 89}}

`A1.B1.C1.etc` or `Dot[A1 , B1, C1]` do not work for me (maybe I did something wrong), but `((A1.B1).C1).etc` does.

As 郑新然 remarked, using an identity matrix as operator in `Fold[#1.#2 &, {{1,0},{0,1}}, list]` produces the correct result.

> {{34, 55}, {55, 89}}

Comment: I think the code `Fold[#1.#2 &, 1, list]` where `1` should be substitute by the matrix `{{1,0},{0,1}}`. And still appreciate your attention to this question.

Comment: @郑新然 Correct observation, I changed my answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: @郑新然 `Fold[Dot, list]` is shorter.