# dot product of one thousand matrices

Tags: matrix, products, dot

I have a time dependent matrix. In a thousand different times with the same time intervals I get the values of the matrices. Now, how can I *DOT Product* these thousand matrices in time order??

Comment: It would be helpful to give some example code that can be used to create an answer for your question. Namely, what have you tried so far? Please, post your code in a copy and paste-able format, i.e., not in a picture. This can be done easily with `Nest` and `Dot`, but without some minimum example from you, such answer may not be as helpful or useful as it could be.

Comment: `clist = FoldList[#1 . #2 &, blist]` assuming `blist` holds the 1000 matrices. If you don't want intermediate steps in order, use `Fold` instead of `FoldList`.

Comment: @Syed slightly shorter `Fold[Dot, blist]`. See also: [`ResourceFunction["AccumulateApply"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/AccumulateApply)

Comment: @Syed oop `Fold` may actually be what I was thinking of! In some of my work I do precisely what the OP here would like to do, but it has been some time since I wrote that part of the code. Good recommendations from flinty also!

Comment: Do you have the matrices already stored in memory, e.g. in `blist`, or are they so big that you have to generate them on the fly?

Comment: Also note that `Fold[Dot, blist]` is not faster than simply `Dot @@ blist`...the time necessary grows enormously, and I think you need another strategy. so, I don't think this question should be closed

Comment: okay, correction: if your dot product blows up, *then* the time it takes grows enormously! otherwise it's fine, so now I think this question should be closed. Compare `Dot @@ Array[RandomReal[] &, {1000, 100, 100}]` (which might need to be aborted) with `Dot @@ Array[RandomReal[]/50 &, {1000, 100, 100}]`, the latter of which is properly normalized.

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/83072/why-does-partitioning-increase-dot-execution-speed